# I Need This Searchbar To Be Clickable With Custom URL's Unrelated To The Actual Text Results

Tags: javascript, string, hyperlink, searchbar

OK Take-2. Thank you for the constructive criticism. My first post. The code I posted has a list of countries, and that's all. The problem is, there is no way for the user to click on one of the results and go to a related web page. Making the countries part of the URL is not the solution because the page names are different than the text results on the search. I think is has to be a separate list, that parallels the text. Something like:

```
    '/travel/page001.html',
    '/travel/page002.html',
    '/travel/page003.html',
    '/travel/page004.html',
    '/travel/page005.html',
    '/travel/page006.html',
    '/travel/page007.html',
    '/travel/page008.html',
    '/travel/page009.html',
    '/travel/page010.html',
    '/travel/page011.html'
```

```js
function search() {
  let listContainer = document.getElementById('list');
  let listItems = document.getElementsByClassName('listItem');
  let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let noResults = true;
  
  for (i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    if (!listItems[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input) || input === "") {
      listItems[i].style.display = "none";
      continue;
    } else {
      listItems[i].style.display = "flex";
      noResults = false;
    }

    listContainer.style.display = noResults ? "none" : "block";
  }
}

function loadSearchData() {
  // Data to be used in the searchbar
  let countries = [
    'Australia',
    'Austria',
    'Brazil',
    'Canada',
    'Denmark',
    'Egypt',
    'France',
    'Germany',
    'USA',
    'Vietnam'
  ];

  // Get the HTML element of the list
  let list = document.getElementById('list');
  
  // Add each data item as an <a> tag
  countries.forEach((country) => {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.innerText = country;
    a.classList.add("listItem");
    list.appendChild(a);
  })
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Searchbar</title>
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" -->
</head>

<body onload="loadSearchData()">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Search Parts</h2>
    <input id="searchbar" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="search()" type="text" \n name="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
    <div id="list"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please see [ask], then revise to be more specific about the intended behavior and the problem you're facing. Also take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Comment: I would turn `countries` into an Object: `countries  = {Australia: '/travel/page001.html', Austria: '/travel/page002.html',...}`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can use the below template notation. Just wrap the string in ticks and reference country with ${country}.

```
a.href = `/country/${country}`;
```

I also took it upon myself to update your loop. instead of changing the style, toggling a Class will give you way more abilities down the line like easily changing colors, borders or whatever.

```js
function search() {
  let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  
  const links = document.querySelectorAll("#list a");
  
  links.forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.toggle("active",(e.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(input) && input != ""))
  });
}

function loadSearchData() {
  // Data to be used in the searchbar
  let countries = [
    'Australia',
    'Austria',
    'Brazil',
    'Canada',
    'Denmark',
    'Egypt',
    'France',
    'Germany',
    'USA',
    'Vietnam'
  ];

  // Get the HTML element of the list
  let list = document.getElementById('list');
  
  // Add each data item as an <a> tag
  countries.forEach((country) => {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = `/country/${country}`;
    a.innerText = country;
    a.classList.add("listItem");
    list.appendChild(a);
  })
}

loadSearchData()
```

```css
#list a{display:none;}
#list a.active{display:flex;}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Search Parts</h2>
    <input id="searchbar" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="search()" type="text" \n name="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
    <div id="list"></div>
  </div>
```